# How to get the closest previous element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the closest object tag from the currently selected object tag. But it has to be strictly above. Suppose I have the object with id `A`. How can I get the closest object tag above it? In this case I want to get the object tag with id `B`. Each div container can contain a object tag or something else.

```
<div class="message">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <object id="C"></object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <object id="B"></object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <object id="A"></object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <object id="Z"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: What prevented you from reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `this` is the object with ID `A`

```
$(this).closest('.message').prevUntil('.message:has(object)').prev().find('object');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/afzfcn02/)

traverses up to the closest `.message` then checks previous elements until it finds one that contains an `object` tag, then it stops, but it stops at the element before that tag, so we call `prev` to go one step further, and then use `find` to find the object tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling element.  That will get you partway there, but since each 'message' `div` is not guaranteed to contain an `object` element you'll need to use [prevUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) or run your own iteration/search.

For instance:

```
var lastObj = $("#A");
var parent = lastObj.parent();
var previousObject = parent.prevUntil(".message:has(object)").prev().find("object");
```

Or without `prevUntil()`:

```
var lastObj = $("#A");
var parent = lastObj.parent();
var previousObject = undefined;
while (parent.length > 0 && ! previousObject) {
    parent = parent.prev();
    if (parent.find("object").length > 0) {
        previousObject = parent.find("object");
    }
}
```

Or as a runnable code snippet (using classes instead of `object` tags):

```js
$(".object").click(function(){
  var myId = this.id;
  var prevId = undefined;
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var previousObject = undefined;
  while (parent.length > 0 && ! previousObject) {
    parent = parent.prev();
    if (parent.find(".object").length > 0) {
        previousObject = parent.find(".object");
        prevId = previousObject.attr("id");
    }
  }
  
  alert("clicked=" + myId + ", previous=" + prevId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span class="object" id="C">C</object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span class="object" id="B">B</object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span class="object" id="A">A</object>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <span class="object" id="Z">Z</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
var objs=$('object').toArray();
$('.message').on('click',function(){
    var elem=$(this).children().get(0);
    if(objs.indexOf(elem)-1>=0){
        console.log(objs[objs.indexOf(elem)-1]);
        console.log(objs[objs.indexOf(elem)-1].id);
    }
});
```