# How do we get the closest previous element in a complex document?

Tags: jquery

We were trying to get the closest previous element using jQuery using the [codes given here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30689198/7172091)

In [this fiddle, the same code is not working](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/h7b5v8yt/), without throwing any console errors.

```
var lastObj = $("#SomeButton");
var parent = lastObj.parent();
var previousObject = parent.prevUntil(".title:has(h4)").prev().find("h4");
  alert(previousObject.text());
```

Can someone please help me understand the problem here?

One possible way is [having multiple parents](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/h7b5v8yt/4/), but this will break if the number of parents is dynamic :(

Comment: Previous element to what? The button? Your markup is different from the code example so obviously it won't work.

Comment: @Ionut, Exactly, I need the closest to the button only. What is the problem in my code? I'm new into jQuery, can you please help?

Comment: student, see my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to help you out. Also, I would suggest you to use `jQuery`'s `.on` click event since you said it's about `jQuery`. So I changed your code a bit and added an on click event and replaced `$('#SomeButton')` with `$(this)` to get this clicked button:

```js
$('.SomeButtonClass').on('click', function(){
  var lastObj = $(this);
  var parent = lastObj.parent();
  var previousObject = parent.closest(":has(h4)").find('h4');
  console.log(previousObject.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="header">
    <h4 class="title">Title 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div id="someDiv">
      <div class="someOtherDiv">
        <div class="OneMoreDiv">
          <button id="SomeButton" class="SomeButtonClass">button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="top">
  <div class="header">
    <h4 class="title">Title 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div id="someDiv">
      <div class="someOtherDiv">
        <div class="OneMoreDiv">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ionut, it's been a great help!

Comment: @student, awesome. I'm happy to help.